# How to see a returned html rendered as a webpage with postman

Tags: postman

[image]

I'm working with postman to test a flask app, I've noticed (like in the screenshot) that I am getting the returned HTML. I know in the past I was able to see the returned HTML rendered as a webpage, but now I can't (despite clicking on various buttons). How can I see the returned html as a webpage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to view the response output as a webpage you must hit the preview button.  For example when in raw response mode you get the following:[image]
Then in Preview mode you get the following:[image]

Comment: Note that JavaScript will not be enabled in the Preview. More on this issue https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2646